# Delete by Date In Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a field that contains a date in it, and what i need to do is to delete dates that are 2 years old, so if a date in a field is 6/16/2014 in will delete it, 6/16/2013 will keep it. Is it possible?

Comment: How do you want to do this?  Query, vba?

Comment: But 6/16/2013 is two years old, and you will both delete it and keep it ... not possible.

Comment: I wanted to be a query, I need it to delete records that have a date in a date field (format: mm/dd/yyyy) that less than a year. So if date in 6/16/214 it will delete It and everything after, and 6/15/2014 and under will keep it.

Answer (score 0):

A SQL query like this should do the trick, deleting anything 6/17/2013 or after (which I think is what you were looking for).

```
DELETE FROM MyTableName WHERE MyDateField >= #6/17/2013#
```

I find it's safer to use `>= #6/17/2013#` rather than `> #6/16/2013#`, since often specifying a date without a time means that day at midnight, so anything that happened after midnight on 6/16 is still considered "after" and gets deleted.

Also, you might want to make a copy of your .mdb file before you go doing mass deletes, just in case. :-)

For further reading, check out
[Office.com: Access SQL: basic concepts, vocabulary, and syntax](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-SQL-basic-concepts-vocabulary-and-syntax-444D0303-CDE1-424E-9A74-E8DC3E460671?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

---

**EDIT:** To automatically use today's date minus 2 years, the query would become

```
DELETE FROM MyTableName WHERE MyDateField > DATEADD("yyyy", -2, DATE())
```

Course, that might also delete events 6/16/2013 and after, rather than 6/17/2013 and after. If that's a problem, you could tweak it with either nested DATEADD statements, one to subtract 2 years and one to add a day.

FMI: [Access DATEADD() Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/dateadd.php)

Comment: If there is a way to tell Access what is today's date with function and go from there, instead of manually putting in a query?