# Trying to delete records or reports in MS Access before a certain date

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, sql-delete

I have a Microsoft Access Database file.
I wanted to delete records older than 5 years in it.
I made a backup before starting to modify the file.

I was able to run a query and then run the command below and append it or update it to the database file.

```
DELETE FROM Inspections Report WHERE Date <= #01/01/2013#
```

I used the example:
[Delete by Date In Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877787/delete-by-date-in-access)

The records still seem to be in there.

**My desired Output:**

A analogy to what I am trying to do would be the bottom left corner of a Microsoft Word file where you see page 1 of 10 when it should say page 1 of 5 after deleting pages.

Comment: You need brackets around reserved words and table/field names with "special" characters: `DELETE FROM [Inspections Report] WHERE [Date] <= #01/01/2013#`.

Answer (score 0):

To run a sequel command from Access VBA you need to preface it with `DoCmd.RunSQL` or `CurrentDb.Execute`, and then put your SQL coding in quotes.

Also, the space is probably causing an issue - if the table you're deleting records from is called "Inspections Report" you'd enclose both those words in square brackets to show its a single entity.

Finally "Date" is a special word in Access, and it doesn't like it when you use it as a field name, as it can cause problems when referencing that field later on. You might try something like "InspectionDate".

So your code would look like this:

`DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM [Inspections Report] WHERE InspectionDate <=#1/01/2013#"`

If you have a static date, you'd probably only need to complete this process once, which you could just do in the table by filtering - filter for before that date, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to select all that match that criteria, and hit delete. It will ask if you want to delete them, and you may see that the number of records it's trying to delete is only the number that satisfies your set criteria.

Of course, if you're interested in never having records older than a certain number of years, you could go for something in the original coding like `> DATEADD("yyyy", -5, DATE())` and set it to execute every time you launch the database.

Answer (score 0):

DELETE Table1.*, Table1.VisitDate
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.VisitDate)<=#1/1/2013#));

I suggest you make the query object and save it, so it appears in the Navigation Pane and can be tested manually. [In which case you use Query Design View and don't need the syntax above]

Then use the OpenQuery method to fire that query.